# Is "conseguido cambiar la información de usuario" correct transaltion?

Tags: traducción

"Conseguido cambiar la información de usuario" correct translation for "succesfully changed users information"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically yes, but I would say something like «Información de usuario cambiada correctamente» or «Cambiados con éxito los datos del usuario»

Comment: Thanks, I do have problems finding the best ways of translating these kind of messages.

Comment: But "Users" is plural, the correct traduction would be : "Información de los usuarios cambiada con éxito"

Comment: @Jimmy: I'm not sure. The original English sentence is incorrect.  It should be either "Successfully changed user's information" or "Successfully changed users' information."  As it's written, it's incorrect and ambiguous whether it's a single user or multiple users. A third, less likely possibility, is that it's correct, and means "the information about users," but given the original Spanish attempt, I think that's pretty unlikely. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would use "La información del usuario ha sido actualizada"

Answer (score 0):

Some better translations would be:

"Se ha podido cambiar la información de usuario"

"Se ha cambiado la información de usuario"

I work as a computer technician in South America but, I am from the US.